# Use of unresolved identifier NSCalendarUnitDay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

I just updated Xcode to its 6.3 version.

Except all the fixes I have to make regarding `as` (mainly), I have some warnings that just appeared (which is weird as it states it is since iOS 8.0).

My code

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(self, toDate: date, toUnitGranularity: .DayCalendarUnit) == .OrderedAscending
```

is now shows a warning

```
'DayCalendarUnit' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead
```

Fine, then I'll change `.DayCalendarUnit` by `NSCalendarUnitDay`

Now I get an error saying:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSCalendarUnitDay'
```

I'm confuse, can someone explain me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.CalendarUnitDay`. NSCalendar is a native Objective-C framework and the error messages aren't for swift.

Comment: "updated" is kind of a broad statement.  The error message is intended for Objective-C where it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think Apple thought the name of those units weren't meaningful like .DayCalendarUnit, so they have modified it to sound more sensible and explanative as .CalendarUnitDay.

Similar modifications have been done in Objective-C. NSDayCalendarUnit is deprecated and you have to use NSCalendarUnitDay.

The problem in your case is that you are receiving deprecation warning of Objective-C instead of Swift. We hope Apple fixes it soon.

Hope that explains...

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode 7.3 use .Day which is a property of NSCalendarUnit struct