# 'DayCalendarUnit was deprecated. Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead' doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nscalendar

```
let dateComponents = calendar.components(.DayCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
```

I got error:

`'DayCalendarUnit' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead`

But when I replace these names with those suggested by Apple

```
let dateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)
```

I get error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSCalendarUnitDay'
```

Comment: Yes, same problem here.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529925/use-of-unresolved-identifier-nscalendarunitday

Answer (score 18):

Along with latest Swift 2.0:

```
NSCalendarUnit.Day
```

hence you will now have:

```
let dateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate: date)
```

Answer (score 16):

try this

```
NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest Swift works with just `.day`, `.month` etc.